# Make rows from two diffent coloumn in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, pivot-table, rows

can anyone help me ? 
I want make rows from two different coloumn in postgres.
this my query :

```
    SELECT inactivedays from p_interval as  inactivedays
  UNION 
    SELECT reminderdays FROM p_interval as reminderdays
```

this result myquery :

[image]

but i want like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then include the headings in the subqueries:

```
SELECT 'inactivedays' as col, inactivedays from p_interval
UNION ALL
SELECT 'reminderdays' as reminderdays FROM p_interval;
```

Answer (score 0):

Little correctiion in above query:

```
SELECT 'inactivedays' as col, inactivedays from p_interval
UNION ALL
SELECT 'reminderdays' as col, reminderdays FROM p_interval;
```